# Why can we not define a low + top-level const pointer to a pointer to int?

Tags: c++

1. Define int and pointer to int:

   `int i = 22, *p = &i;`
2. Define pointer that is low level and top-level const:

   `const int *const cp = p;`

   (2) is alright - const point with no permission to change the value (of i)
3. Definie a pointer to a pointer that is low+top-level const:

   `const int **const cp_2_p = &p;`

   (3) isn't alright, why?

   `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int **' to 'const int **const`

I'd expect to be able to define a pointer to a pointer to `int` where I cannot change the address it points to nor the address the pointer it points to, points to.

Comment: What does "high" and "low" level pointer mean?

Comment: See also [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html) for why it's a bad idea to convert from `int **` to `int const **`.

Comment: @KirilKirov - not high and low level pointer -> high and/or low level constness; but I was wrong it's called 'top-level' and 'low-level'; top-level means you can't change the address. low-level means you cannot change the value in that address.

Comment: @zehelvion you have that backwards. A low-level const means the address cannot be changed, top-level const means the value cannot be changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, `const` applies to the item to its left. The exception of `const T` is present for historical reasons, and is the conventional alternative to `T const`.

`cp` is declared as a **constant** pointer to a constant `int`.

`cp_2_p` is declared as a constant pointer to a **non-constant** pointer to a constant int.

You would need to declare `cp_2_p` like this for the types to be compatible:

```
const int *const *const cp_2_p
```

Comment: Or as "const int *const *", for a non-const pointer to "const pointer to const int".

Comment: @dascandy - Thanks a lot, that really covers up the all top-level low-level const "mystery" when it comes to pointers to pointers. so in ** - the first * refers to the pointer I'm pointing to and the second to the pointer I'm declaring, correct?

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite Yep, exactly. Read from right to left. That's also why the "int const" is slightly more correct in that regard, it reads easier from right to left.

Comment: @dascandy Alright, I'm confused again. I can have a constant pointer to a none constant pointer but I can't have a constant pointer to a none constant pointer to a const value?

Comment: No, sure you can. "(1) int (2) * (3) * (4)" => (1) and (2) are the same location, that's whether the "int" is const. (3) indicates whether the pointer pointing to the int is const. (4) indicates whether the pointer, pointing to an int pointer, is const. You can extend the list ad infinitum but you don't typically need more than 2 *'s. Incidentally, same locations are also used for "volatile".

Comment: So the problem was that I tried to point to a const int through a pointer "that wouldn't play along" (p) cause it is pointing to a none const int and therefore the error. The pointer I'm pointing to knows it's not pointing to const so I can't "pretend" to point to a pointer to const.

Comment: You take the type you have "const int * const" and to make a pointer out of that, add a " * " to the end => "const int * const * ". To make a const pointer to that, add " * const" to the end => "const int * const * const". To find out the type something points to, strip off from the right until and including the first " * " - so in your example the final target is "const int".